# How to disable or inactive checkbox when select current in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to disable other checkbox when current checkbox is checked or selected.

Following is my code. I have tried but not work

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test" class="test">One
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test" class="test">Two
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test" class="test">Three
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test" class="test">Four
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test" class="test">Five
```

**JQuery Script**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".test").each(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                $(this).prop('checked',true);
                $('.test').prop('checked',false);
            }
        })
    })  
</script>
```

Comment: Do not use duplicate ID!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `change` event handler and read `:checked` value of the checkbox clicked. Disable or enable other checkboxes as per `:checked` value

See below code

NOTE: Always use unique ids for all HTML elements otherwise you will end up with wrong result for the jquery script with id selectors

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".test").on('change', function(){
           $('.test').not(this).prop('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test1" class="test">One
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test2" class="test">Two
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test3" class="test">Three
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test4" class="test">Four
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test5" class="test">Five
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use `click` or `change` event, then you don't need to use `$(this).prop('checked',true);` and do not use duplicate `id`

```js
$('.test').click(function() {
  let $this = $(this);
  if ($this.is(':checked')) {
    $('.test').not($this).attr('disabled', true)
  } else {
    $('.test').attr('disabled', false)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="test" class="test">One</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="test" class="test">Two</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="test" class="test">Three</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="test" class="test">Four</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="test" class="test">Five</label>
```

For make `disable` you need to use `'disabled', true`.